# What should we use in replacement of Bot Framework Composer

Tags: botframework

The Bot Framework Composer use LUIS and deploy LUIS to Azure. However, LUIS is deprecated and Azure doesn't accept the deploy anymore.

What should we use in replacement to the Bot Framework Composer to build our bot using the new CLU service which replaces LUIS?

I know that for already deployed services, it's possible to use CLU URLs inside BOT Composer and everything works fine.

However, when creating a new BOT, on the first deployment the LUIS deployment is required and the deployment fails. How could we work around this?